# Sample code to set target audience for Each items in the Spfx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

Is it possible to set the target audience for each items in the SPFX webpart. Please let me know if any sample code or article is there for that.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide unique permissions to each list item then you have to first stop inheriting permissions at each item level and then assign the permissions to the required users. You can use pnpjs https://pnp.github.io/ role assignments to achieve this

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/security/#role-assignments

please note the supported limit of unique permissions for items in a list or library is 50,000. However, the recommended general limit is 5,000. Making changes to more than 5,000 uniquely permitted items at a time takes longer. Therefore, for large lists, design the list to have as few unique permissions as possible https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/error-share-break-inheritance